# I can't load second url from another function

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I'll try to load second url from 3D touch shortcuts but when I try to load url into webview from another function of viewDidLoad not working.

I'm always getting EXC_BREAKPOINT warning. I have tried all the day can anyone know how to load url into webview from some function called from AppDelegate.

`handleShortcut`: this function calling from AppDelegate.

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loading_splash_text: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loading_splash: UIImageView!
    //internal var urlToLoad: String?

    func didFailLoadWithError(webView: UIWebView) {
        //print("connection error");
        /*
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ConnectionError")
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
         */
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://example.com/");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);

    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        print("did finished");
        loading_splash.hidden = true;
        loading_splash_text.hidden = true;
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        print("did load");
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func handleShortcut() {
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.example.com/");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }

}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
```

public var urlToLoad: String?

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
var vc = FirstViewController()

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if(shortcutItem.type == "com..videos"){
        urlToLoad = "example.com";
    } else if(shortcutItem.type == "com..contact") {
        urlToLoad = "example.com";
    } else if(shortcutItem.type == "com..projects") {
        urlToLoad = "example.com";
    } else {
        urlToLoad = "example.com";
    }

    completionHandler(false)

    vc.handleShortcut();
    print("Shortcut: "+urlToLoad!);
```

Comment: in which line does the app crash?

Comment: webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
this line gives, Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100006a10c) when function called.

Comment: This makes no sense: `completionHandler(false); vc.handleShortcut();` You must not do anything _after_ calling the `completionHandler`; it means you have _completed_ everything. And anyway, what's the purpose of the `false`?